# Basic Javascript / jQuery math game: Why can't I evaluate the second time I run this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, math

Self-taught newbie JS programmer here.  I'm trying to practice what I've learned by making a basic addition game.  It's not terribly slick right now but I'm just trying to get the basic functionality down.

All I'm trying to do right now is continuously generate questions after the user has answered correctly (without refreshing the page). And it works *the first time around only.*

First, I created a function to generate random numbers I can evaluate and put them on the page. [Click here to see the jsfiddle I made](http://jsfiddle.net/StephanieQ/r0os9voo/)

```
    // GENERATE AND INSERT NUMBERS

function getRandomInt (min, max) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
function Operation() {
    var self = this;
    var $numberOne = getRandomInt(0,20);
    var $numberTwo = getRandomInt(0,20);
    $numberHolderOne.html($numberOne);
    $numberHolderTwo.html($numberTwo);
    self.quest = $numberOne + $numberTwo;
    self.solution = eval (self.quest);
}
    Operation();
```

Then I evaluate, I want to alert to tell the user if they're right, wrong or not putting in valid characters.  If the user is right I want to put a new question on the page.

```
            //EXECUTE ON CLICK
$goButton.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myAnswer = $('input:text').val();

            if (myAnswer == self.solution)  {
            alert( "You did it!" );
            new Operation();
                }     
            else if (isNaN(myAnswer)) {
            alert("Numbers Only yo!");
        }
            else {
            alert("Try Again Please");
        }
     });
```

And like I said it works! ...kinda.  It generates new questions as long as you submit the the right answer to the first question only.  Why? I mean, I'm running a new function and those variables are defined in that function.  Is there something I'm missing? Is this a scope problem?

Comment: Don’t use `new Operation();`, but `Operation();` instead.

Comment: ...Wow, well that was surprisingly simple! Thank you so much for talking the time to read and answer my question :D I'm sure you saved me a lot of time and headache.  Thanks again!

Comment: Unrelated, but `$numberOne` and `$numberTwo` are already integers, so `eval` is pointless (and evil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue arrived due to explicit initialization of `Operation` which gives very firstly tried Math operation again! *Ex.* If you've got 10 + 2 at first i.e. 12 and if you say `New Operation()`; it gave exactly same 12 again which is not matching with answer of numbers generated by `getRandomInt` & you've typed in Textbox! So, no need to reinitialize it.

Try out below `click` function:

```
        //EXECUTE ON CLICK
        $goButton.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var myAnswer = $('input:text').val();
            alert(eval (self.quest));
                    if (myAnswer == self.solution)  {
                    alert( "You did it!" );

                    Operation();

                }     else if (isNaN(myAnswer)) {
                alert("Numbers Only yo!");
            }       
                else {
                    alert("Try Again Please");
                }   
        });
```

Here is [working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r0os9voo/10/)

Comment: The OP will benefit more from your answer if you explain what the issue was and how the fix works. You are not addressing any of the OP's questions: *" It generates new questions as long as you submit the the right answer to the first question only. Why? I mean, I'm running a new function and those variables are defined in that function. Is there something I'm missing? Is this a scope problem?"*

Comment: Thank you for that explanation!  I think I understand it now, for the most part anyway.  I wish I had enough rep to vote up your answer.  @Felix Kling Thank you for your concern but I think I've got it. It seems I just have to work it out and learn from experience. "Hey, this works, this doesn't." sort of thing.  Thank you guys for your help and input :D

Answer (score 2):

you have created the variable self local to the block please make it accessible to function you are writing for go button.

I have edited the fiddle, please refer this Link: [js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kartikupadhyay/r0os9voo/8/)

Comment: Neat, that works too! Thank you for solving and explaining it :D